# Handling special cases with generics in Swagger

Tags: java, generics, swagger

I am adding Swagger to an existing project to generate documentation. It mostly works great, but there's some edge-cases that produce some weird documentation and I'm wondering if there's a way to handle them.

One web method will operate on generic types, looking something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractServiceClass<T>
{
    @ApiOperation(value="blah blah",tags={ "Generic methods"})
    @Path("/doGenericThing")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    @Produces({ "application/xml", "application/json" })
    public T doGenericThing(@ApiParam T entity)
    {
    //...
    }
}

@Api(value="/a.b.c")
@Path("a.b.c")
public class ConcreteService extends AbstractServiceClass<SomeEntityType>{
//...
}
```

When swagger generates the documentation for `ConcreteService`, it generates documentation for the method `doGenericThing`, but is not able to determine that the parameter type is `SomeEntityType`. Is there a way to tell Swagger about the parameter type of the inherited method when it generates the documentation of the concrete service class?

I have a similar situation where he generic method will only work on certain entities. Those entities have a custom annotation applied to them, and the code is able to determine if the given input is something that it can handle. Is there a way to tell swagger to not generate method documentation for inherited methods in certain service classes marked as `@Api`?

I'm rather new to Swagger and I'm not sure if it's capable of handling these scenarios. I'm open to adding mapping files, or even extending the API (if there's a reasonable and documented way to do this) to add this custom functionality. Rewriting these classes so that they are easier for Swagger to digest is probably not going to be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest opening an issue on https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues to track this.  There are definitely limitations due to type erasure that cannot be overcome by reading the implementation at runtime.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure if it was *supposed* to work, or not. I realize type erasure could cause problems for some situations, and I wasn't sure if my first problem was one of those situations. I don't know about other people, but I seem to be seeing these types of generic web services increasingly often. The code bases are smaller and easier to work with, but obviously this generic approach causes problems with tools like Swagger.

Comment: Yes, supporting generics at runtime is very difficult to do thanks to type erasure.  There are tricks but they will affect the implementation techniques.